# Задать попеременное значение в цикле массива

Tags: циклы, php

Задача заключается в том, чтобы при парсинге строк из файла обрабатывать (заменять html теги строк таблицы) с одних на другие. Скрипт с работой справляется. Однако не пойму, как реализовать следующее.

У нас имеется таблица, в которой строки надо по очереди оборачивать в два разных стиля, `tr class="sp sp1"` и `tr class="sp sp1"`, то есть в процессе обработки нам встречается в строке тег `tr`, он заменятся первый раз на `tr class="sp sp1"`, а второй раз - уже на `tr class="sp sp2"`. В приведенном коде у меня получилось так, что при обработке первой строки присваивается `tr class="sp sp1"`, при обработке второй строки `tr class="sp sp2"`, а надо, чтобы в рамках обработки одной строки они чередовались.

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно составить вложенный цикл.

```
$handle = fopen("test-1.csv", "r"); 
    $stroka=0;
        while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 6000, ";"))
        {

                $table = (str_replace("'", "\"", $data[2]));

                $tmp = str_replace('<td colspan="2" class="tables_separator">', '<td class="h" colspan="2">', $data[2]);

                if ($stroka===0) 
                {
                $tmp = str_replace('<tr>', '<tr class="sp sp1">', $tmp);
                $stroka=1;
                echo 'sp sp1</br>';
                }
                else
                {
                $tmp = str_replace('<tr>', '<tr class="sp sp2">', $tmp);
                $stroka=0;
                echo 'sp sp2</br>';
                }
```

Comment: @mrFreeman, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Если вам это надо для оформления страницы, то можно использовать псевдокласс CSS.

**Описание**
Псевдокласс `:nth-child` используется для добавления стиля к элементам на основе нумерации в дереве элементов.

**Синтаксис**

```
элемент:nth-child(odd | even | <число> | <выражение>) {...}
```

**Значения**

1. odd - все нечетные номера элементов.
2. even - все четные номера элементов.
3. число - порядковый номер дочернего элемента относительно своего родителя. Нумерация начинается с 1, это будет первый элемент в списке.
4. выражение - задается в виде an+b, где a и b целые числа, а n — счетчик, который автоматически принимает значение 0, 1, 2...

Если a равно нулю, то оно не пишется и запись сокращается до b. Если b равно нулю, то оно также не указывается и выражение записывается в форме an. a и b могут быть отрицательными числами, в этом случае знак плюс меняется на минус, например: 5n-1.

За счет использования отрицательных значений a и b некоторые результаты могут также получиться отрицательными или равными нулю. Однако на элементы оказывают влияние только положительные значения из-за того, что нумерация элементов начинается с 1.

Источник: http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

**Вариант 2**

Eсть еще вариант:

```
  $i = 1;
  $tbl = "<table>";
  while ( $data = fgetcsv($handle, 6000, ';') ) { 
    if ($i%2 == 0){
      $tbl .= "<tr class='sp sp1'>";
    } else {
      $tbl .= "<tr class='sp sp2'>";
    }
    $i++;
  }
  $tbl .= "</table>";
```

То есть в данном коде мы задали цикл и уже внутри цикла проверяем остаток от деления "счетчика" на 2, это поможет определить четность/нечетность переменной-счетчика.
После условного оператора увеличиваем значение переменной-счетчика.

Источник: собственные соображения.
P.S. Во втором варианте возможны некоторые ошибки, но суть остается той же самой...

Comment: Ответ с описанием псевдокласса стиля достаточно сложный в данном случае. Второй вариант дает такой же результат, что и мой изначальный, он в первую строку (которую берет из файла) в таблицу пишет sp1 во вторую строку sp2.

Кажется тут надо сперва считать количество вхождений в строке элемента, подлежащего поочередной замене, а потом уже циклом проходиться и менять поочередно.

Но как это в коде реализовать сам не еще не придумал. Только что к этому пришел в догадках.

Comment: >>>> в рамках обработки одной строки они чередовались

Не понял. Вам надо, чтобы чередовались Столбцы таблицы?
тег tr - это строка. К какому элементу надо переключать класс? Если что, можете писать мне на e-mail: garmayev@yandex.ru